# jQuery animate effects on Bootstrap-Multiselect

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to add an effect to flash a bootstrap-multiselect dropdown button green when the value is changed. I want to use:

```
$optionSelect.multiselect({ nonSelectedText: 'Select option', numberDisplayed: 1});
$optionSelect.effect('highlight', {color: 'green'}, 500);
```

Unfortunately, this causes the multiselect to completely break, splitting up the select and the button. The effect then gets applied to the multiselect portion, leaving the dropdown button element unselected. How can I cause the button to highlight without causing the bootstrap-multiselect element to split in two?

Answer (score 0):

I offer using **Animate.css** to make animation in an event instead of jquery ui

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

you could download and customize the css file and put the flash class to your elements anytime you want.

Comment: I unfortunately have to stick to jquery. .effect() works on everything else, not sure why multiselect gives it an issue.